# How to install QT on Ubuntu for Cross compiling

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, qmake

I know there are tons of informations out there on the web about my question.
I have searched and tried for at least 2 days to get my setup up and running. But there are many unclear points and i would be very happy if someone could help me with answering my questions.

My situation:

I have an i.MX6 Eval Board on my desk which is running uboot with Linux Kernel 4.9.2. There is no distro on top. Just the kernel with busybox. 
Attached to the board is a LCD TFT which is accesed through the Framebuffer. There is no GPU in the Processor.

To compile uboot and the kernel, i use the linaro toolchain gcc-linaro-6.2.1-2016.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf  This toolchain is located at /opt/toolchain. The compilation of the kernel and uboot works without any problems.

Now i would like to start the application development with QT Creator. I have therefore read a lot of topics on various forums and sites on the web. Unfortunately i did not get it working.

First of all i have a confusion about the meaning of the title: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-install.html

There is a guide how to install "Installing Qt for Embedded Linux" Does this mean that this version is for an embedded linux, so it means that it has to be installed on the embedded device. Or does it mean that it guides you how to install QT to develop for a target system and install QT on an other system?

Before i wrote this question, i have already installed QT5.7 from their website. After some googling, i figured out that there are some changes in the windowsystem between 4.8 and 5.x. Since i dont have any GPU and therefore i dont have any OpenGL support, im not sure whether i should better go with 4.8 or whether i could use the 5.x version. Usually i tend to use the latest versions if possible.

Next i saw, that i have to define the sysroot directory. In the sysroot directory there have to be the compiled libs for qt for the arm architecture. Is there a precompiled version of these libs or do i have to compile them by my self? If yes, where to start?

EDIT:
In some tutorials they use the angstrom toolchain with a "qte" suffix My linaro toolchain does not have such an suffix. Is it also possible to use my linaro toolchain to build the qt applications?

Maybe you will notice that im new to QT and to the Embedded Linux world. 
Anyhow i hope there are people out there who will be happy to share their knowledge about this topic with me.

Thanks.